# How do I capture the output of a command and put it in a label?

Tags: application-development, python

This is an extract from the code of a Quickly application I'm working on:

```
# Code for other initialization actions should be added here.

self.apachestart = self.builder.get_object("apachestart")
self.label1 = self.builder.get_object("label1")

def on_apachestart_clicked(self, widget):
    subprocess.call(['sudo', 'service', 'apache2', 'start'])
```

Now when I press the button to start Apache (named `apachestart`), it prints to standard out in the terminal that the server was started:

```
* Starting web server apache2  [ OK ]
```

How do I get that text output from the terminal to be shown in a label?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4760517/247696

Answer (score 5):

This is not really a Quickly question, but a  pure Python one.

Have a look at the [`Subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) documentation, especially the [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) method.

You could do something like this (untested):

```
def on_apachestart_clicked(self, widget):
    result = subprocess.check_output(['sudo', 'service', 'apache2', 'start'])
    if result.split('[ ')[1].startswith('OK'):
        text = "Success!"
    else:
        text = "Failed!"
    self.label1.set_text(text)
```

Maybe also catch the `CalledProcessError` in the call.

Comment: I tryed your sugesstion but i get an error in terminal : "IndentationError: expected an indented block" ?? when i use space to move the line I get another error : "if result.split('[ ')[1].startswith('OK'):
NameError: name 'result' is not defined
"?? What seems to be the problem? Anyway the example is good to what i want but what I reealy wanted is to print the terminal output text to my label1.THNKS!I wait for another suggestion if you like!!

Comment: Please, read a Python tutorial first before starting programming in the wild. Or atleast learn how to Google your error messages. An `IndendationError` means you're messing up your indentation (ah yes). Never mix tabs and spaces, follow PEP8 and use 4 spaces to indent. Remember, Python uses indentation to mark new code lines etc, not curly braces and semi-colons like many other languages. So it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong here, you'll have to check for yourself, or if you really, really, really can't figure it out, post the entire code.

Comment: Now I'm able to open window but when I click on button I get another error in terminal : `code` [sudo] password for caezsar: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/caezsar/test/test/TestWindow.py", line 40, in on_apachestart_clicked
    if result.split('[ ')[1].startswith('OK'):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What seems to be wrong?I'm new in python and sure need some professional help!can we talk on yahoo messenger ? caezsar is my id if you wanna give a help hand! THNKS!

Comment: If you need some professional help, get professional help! For example, there are [training classes](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonTraining) available. See [this link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) and [this link](http://python.org/community/).

Comment: Also, I would recommend stackoverflow, as these are basic programming questions and not related to Ubuntu really.